# org.json.JSONException: No value for salim_innova

Tags: android, json

I know am asking a question which has answers in SO. But I am not able to solve my problem with those solutions that's why I am asking another one. My exact Problem is, I have Json data like this

```
[{"deviceID":"demo","deviceDetails":[]}, 
 {"deviceID":"salim_fiat","deviceDetails":[{"accountID":"gts","deviceID":"salim_fiat","timestamp":"1463584964","latitude":"13.003460008185357","longitude":"77.59789001662284","speed":"4.2","heading":"145.7","altitude":"895.9","address":"","distance":"242","odometer":"242","IbatVolts":"4.219","EbatVolts":"12.392","ITempr":"32","fuelLevel":"0","inputState":"0","IgnRuntime":null,"GPSFixType":null,"GPSPDOP":null,"AlertType":null,"speedLimitKPH":"0","isTollRoad":"0"}]},  
 {"deviceID":"salim_innova","deviceDetails":[{"accountID":"gts","deviceID":"salim_innova","timestamp":"1463581191","latitude":"13.002970002125949","longitude":"77.59746002499014","speed":"7.4","heading":"357.2","altitude":"940.2","address":"","distance":"518.2","odometer":"518.2","IbatVolts":"4.226","EbatVolts":"13.491","ITempr":"34","fuelLevel":"0","inputState":"5","IgnRuntime":null,"GPSFixType":null,"GPSPDOP":null,"AlertType":null,"speedLimitKPH":"0","isTollRoad":"0"}]}]
```

Now I want to get the device Id's in spinner (demo , salim_fiat , salim_innova). 
I am getting them perfectly.
When I click on that particular device id, I want to get the corressponding values in textView or spinner. 
for Example if I click on salim_fiat, I want to get accountID,deviceID,timestamp etc....
I tried to get only accountID in the textview but I am unsuccessful.
my console output is

```
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for salim_innova
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:609)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at com.example.lenovo.login.GetList$1$1$override.onItemSelected(GetList.java:80)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at com.example.lenovo.login.GetList$1$1$override.access$dispatch(GetList.java)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at com.example.lenovo.login.GetList$1$1.onItemSelected(GetList.java:0)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:919)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:908)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:53)
05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:878)
05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033)
 05-19 15:43:22.026 25630-25630/com.example.lenovo.login W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

I am pasting all my code here, any help would be very thankful

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i<response.length(); i++)
            {
                try {
                   final JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject(i);
                   // String name = jo.getString("userID");
                    final String account = jo.getString("deviceID");
                    arrayList.add(account);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(GetList.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,arrayList);
                    getDeviceIdSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    getDeviceIdSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            String name1 = getDeviceIdSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            //Toast.makeText(GetList.this, "Nmae is " +name1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            JSONArray jsonArray;
                            String list;
                            try {
                                JSONObject jo1 = jo.getJSONObject(name1);
                                jsonArray = jo1.getJSONArray("deviceDetails");
                                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                                {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                        list = jsonObject1.optString("deviceID");
                                        Toast.makeText(GetList.this, "Device Id" +list, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                        }
                    });


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    rq.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Comment: in the code you posted there is no trace of salim_innovac

Comment: Thanks for reply,   I am sorry I didn't get you in my code salim_innovac is no where.. Can you please tell me clearly

Comment: The problem is that `salim_innova` is not a **key** but rather a **value**. You should look-up by **key**. It seems you want to look-up by value to retrieve a JSON object that has  "deviceID" with a value "salim_innova". I think it is best if you extend ArrayAdapter. Furthermore, your program also needs some re-work - for instance you should rather create an adapter-list for the response-array instead of individual items of the response array. Meaning that you should move the adapter code out of the for-loop.

Comment: @ ishmaelMakitla Thanks a lot for your reply...  if possible can you paste the sample code for spinner which look up with the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonValue);

        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject jo= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray ja=jo.getJSONArray("deviceDetails");
            for (int j=0;j<ja.length();j++) {
                JSONObject jsonObjectDeviceDetails =    ja.getJSONObject(j);
                Log.e("deviceID",jsonObjectDeviceDetails.getString("deviceID"));
            }
        }
```

Try this,jsonValue is the json you are getting from webservice

Comment: Thanks for your post... Actually I am very confused at jsonValue. Which value I need to include. Please tell me from my above code

Comment: jsonValue is the value which you read from webservice onResponse( JSONArray response) method.I have not used jsonarray request but I think your for loop will be some thing like this  for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++)

Comment: I have done like this. The only thing is I want to populate the data according to the selected spinner, In such a situation which JSON value i need to take at this line.                                                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonValue);

Comment: I belive you will have to use the same code again in spinner.But compare the deviceId you get with the string you get from the spinner using string compare methods and get the appropriate values

Answer (score 0):

you are not parsing data correctly. You also you need to change some implementation technique.

1) create an POJO object for the information

```
public class DeviceInfoModel {

private String deviceID;
private ArrayList<DeviceDetailsModel> deviceDetails;

public DeviceInfoModel() {
    this.deviceID = "";
    this.deviceDetails = new ArrayList<>();
}

public String getDeviceID() {
    return deviceID;
}

public void setDeviceID(String deviceID) {
    this.deviceID = deviceID;
}

public ArrayList<DeviceDetailsModel> getDeviceDetails() {
    return deviceDetails;
}

public void setDeviceDetails(ArrayList<DeviceDetailsModel> deviceDetails) {
    this.deviceDetails = deviceDetails;
}
```

}

2) create POJO object for device details

```
public class DeviceDetailsModel {

private String accountID;
private String deviceID;
private String timestamp;


public DeviceDetailsModel() {
    this.accountID = "";
    this.deviceID = "";
    this.timestamp = "";
}

public String getAccountID() {
    return accountID;
}

public void setAccountID(String accountID) {
    this.accountID = accountID;
}

public String getDeviceID() {
    return deviceID;
}

public void setDeviceID(String deviceID) {
    this.deviceID = deviceID;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

}

3) Pars your json response using this way, jsonArrayResponse is your response JsonArray which is coming from web service.

```
deviceInfoModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArrayResponse.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArrayResponse.getJSONObject(i);
            DeviceInfoModel deviceInfoModel = new DeviceInfoModel();
            deviceInfoModel.setDeviceID(jsonObject.getString("deviceID"));
            JSONArray deviceDetailsJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("deviceDetails");
            ArrayList<DeviceDetailsModel> deviceDetailsModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j=0;j<deviceDetailsJsonArray.length();j++){
                JSONObject deviceDetailsJsonObj = deviceDetailsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                DeviceDetailsModel deviceDetailsModel = new DeviceDetailsModel();
                deviceDetailsModel.setDeviceID(deviceDetailsJsonObj.getString("accountID"));
                deviceDetailsModel.setAccountID(deviceDetailsJsonObj.getString("deviceID"));
                deviceDetailsModel.setTimestamp(deviceDetailsJsonObj.getString("timestamp"));
                deviceDetailsModelList.add(deviceDetailsModel);
            }
            deviceInfoModel.setDeviceDetails(deviceDetailsModelList);
            deviceInfoModelList.add(deviceInfoModel);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

4) This way you will get all data in deviceInfoModelList, now create a BaseAdapter and pass the deviceInfoModelList to the adapter and display the list to spinner.

5) after displaying the spinner value use setOnItemSelectedListener for click event.

6) inside the onItemSelected() you can get the object of particular device id using getItemAtPosition() method.

7) now use getters of the object for displaying info. you will be able to display the deviceId's data. This is the correct way, I have tested, I hope it will work for you too.